# jQuery each function not firing with MVC Razor syntax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Fairly new to Razor syntax, but I have some jQuery code on a Razor view like this:-

```
@section Scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        console.log('test1');

        var test = $('#4-10-documentation');

        console.log(test);

        $('#4-10-documentation').each(function () {

            console.log('test2');

        });

        console.log('test3');

    });

</script>

}
```

The firebug console outputs:

```
test1

Object[]

test3
```

So jQuery has no trouble finding the first object when specified directly, but for some reason the `.each` function does not fire at all. Is there some reason why?

Don't worry, the code here is a simplified version of the real code and I am using a class selector not the id selector shown here.

**NOTE:-**
Turns out the element is from a partial view that is loaded via ajax, so the element id is not in existence at document.ready()

Thanks everyone for helping me.

Comment: `$('#4-10-documentation').each` --> why ? `id` must be unique.

Comment: @TusharGupta The OP has mentioned that he is not using id in the 'real' code.

Comment: If you are using class selectors then this looks fine to me. It is creating an object array, which is the expected result, right?

Comment: @Jeevan Jose - The object being written to console is from the first selector (var test ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will always return an object when you attempt to match a selector - whether DOM elements are found matching your selector or not. That's why you see the output `Object[]` when you console.log it.

If you're using Firebug, I'd inspect your HTML to see if the DOM elements you're trying to loop over using jQuery are actually in the rendered HTML. You can also easily check if jQuery has found any DOM elements matching your selector by using `$("#4-10-documentation").length()`

If the result of the `length()` method is 0, then that's the reason why your `.each()` callback is not being called.

Comment: @Roger Pennink - Yep you are right. The length is 0. Turns out the element is loaded via ajax and that is why it cannot be found at document.ready()